# select query and check up of xml value in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to check the existence of username in XML from c#. I have used the following way. Is it the good way of doing that?

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/AppUsers/Users.xml");
            var items = from item in xmlDoc.Elements("Users").Elements("user")
                        where item != null

                        select item;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                if (item.Attribute("username").Value == txtUserName.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The Username is Already Exist!", "Add User", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    return  ;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it returns the correct results, it looks fine.

You could merge the separate check inside the `foreach` loop into the original query, but I don't think it reduces your execution time at all.

```
var items = (from item in xmlDoc.Elements("Users").Elements("user")
             where item != null
                && item.Attribute("username").Value == txtUserName.Text
             select item);

if (items.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Username already exists!", "Add User",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    return;
}
```